# Can I manually replace password hashes in the AIX /etc/security/passwd file?

Tags: passwords, aix

Can I safely replace the password hash in the **AIX** `/etc/security/passwd` file?  Are there any **AIX** quirks that would stand in the way of me just using *vi* to replace the hash?

I want to consolidate the root passwords on my **AIX servers**.  On Solaris, IRIX, and Linux I would compare the password hash in /etc/shadow.  If it wasn't the same, I could replace it with the desired hash.  **AIX** uses `/etc/security/passwd`, which has a different format.  Examples of the password field:

```
password = 2bOR!2Bp8jest
password = {ssha512}06$2bOR!2Bp8jestHAH$hamlet[...]
```

I assume the answer is, "Yes, they can be compared.  They can be replaced, but be *very* careful."

Bonus points (if I have enough rep to award) if someone describes how older AIX versions fail if a newer crypto algorithms, such as `{ssha512}` isn't available.

Comment: I want to emphasize the fact I wish to manually edit /etc/security/passwd.  Are there any AIX quirks that require any extra steps or precautions in addition to just using vi to edit the file?

Comment: Have a look at this. I edit the file myself, but wanted to triple check before telling someone else to do it. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014454472

Comment: Yup, that answers it.  I found another link and answered myself before I saw your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an IBM answer at [Copying AIX password hashes between servers](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/copying_aix_password_hashes_between_servers6?lang=en).  You an use an editor to manually change the password, but there is a command to do that for you.

Quoting:

> get the users password hash out of /etc/security/passwd and then use the "chpasswd" command to change the password on the other server.

The command is:

```
echo 'root:2bOR!2Bp8jest' | chpasswd -ec
```

Comment: Hopefully not actually with a DES hash?

Comment: Just an example using a lispy question.  "2 be or not 2 be p  infinite jest"   PCI requires strong password algorithms here.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that if any user modification to the security file, such as a PAM based password change, at the same time as you write to the security file using vi or any non PAM based commands then two programs are writing to the file at the same time and structure can't be maintained. corruption is guaranteed to occur. This becomes more apparent on systems where the password file is modified frequently and in this way. Definitely do use a PAM authorized method to write to your passwd/security files.